# Unable to Rename the selected folder in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to rename the selected folder. I used JFileChooser to choose a folder, then add this extension .{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D} so that the unauthorized user won't be able to see the real files of the selected folder.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();

    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    fc.showSaveDialog(this);
    jTextField1.setText(""+fc.getSelectedFile());
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    File file3=new File(file.getName());
    File sFile = new File(file.getName()+".{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}");
```

When I run the system that includes the above codes, the system deleted the selected folder. What should I do to rename the selected folder and not to delete it?

Comment: The above code does not rename any folders.

Comment: Merely creating a `File` object does not change anything in the file system.  You can even create a `File` that doesn't refer to any existing file at all.  Also note that simply renaming a directory does not prevent an “unauthorized user” from accessing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these codes:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
fc.showSaveDialog(this);
jTextField1.setText(""+fc.getSelectedFile());
File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
File sFile = new File(file+".{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}")
file.renameTo(sFile);
```